# C - Failing to read socket after about 30 reads

Tags: c, sockets

so I have two processes, one client-process one server-process. The user can issue a command to the client, when a user enters a command the client will send the command length to the server, and after that it will send the actual command.

The server then sends back first the length of the response and then a response.

I can do 5-30 commands or so with no problem at all, but at some point it fails to read enough bytes, despite the correct response  size being received.

The server sends the response in the following way:

```
 str[0] = '\0';
 unsigned long int totalSize = 0;
 while ((fgets(outBuf, MAXOUTPUT, myFile)) != NULL)
 {
    strcat(str, outBuf);
 }
uint32_t *un = 0;
totalSize = strlen(str);
*un = htonl(totalSize); 
result= send(clientFD, un, sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
if(result < 1)
{
    printf("Failed sending message size to client");
    exit(-1);
}
while(token != NULL)
{
    size_t length = strlen(token);
    token[length] = '\n';
    write(clientFD, token, length + 1);
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
```

The client has received the message length correctly(verified with prints) and reads the response this way:

```
result = read(socketFD, recvBuf, bufferlen); //bufferlen is response size
if(result < bufferlen)
{
      perror("read()");
      exit(-1);
}
```

I have verified that the client receives the correct message length every time, including the last one where it fails to read.

So my question is: What are likely reasons that my read sometimes fail to retrieve the full response? It happens after doing about 5-30 commands or so usually, and the perror returned is Error 0 (aka no error to be found).

As an additional note, the commands tested are

ls -la, ls -l, ls.
I have not found a pattern in which commands cause the crash, but I have combined them a lot.

Also: Both the client and server are 32 bit and being run on the same machine locally.

Comment: how is `token` declared? the while loop in client looks buggy to me.

Comment: It is a charpointer, started with token =  strtok(str, "\n")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` (especially on sockets) returns as soon as *some* data is available, it may always return *less* bytes than you asked for. In this case, you will need to repeat the read until you have read enough data:

```
size_t bytes_read = 0;
while (bytes_read < bufferlen) {
    result = read(socketFD, recvBuf + bytes_read, bufferlen - bytes_read);
    if (result < 0) {
        perror("read()");
        exit(-1);
    }
    bytes_read += result;    
}
```

Comment: Hm, seem to have helped a lot even if I sitll get the error, but this time it appears the command wasn't properly received. So guess I just gotta fix the other read too.

Comment: That would be strange, because --unless I made a mistake-- the loop should terminate only on error or if there have been exactly `bufferlen` bytes read.

Comment: Edited my comment, I think the problem now is just the other read(that reads command size), which should be solveable the same way. Thank you, I think you fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The TCP socket works on a byte stream concept. The server is adding bytes to the byte stream, and the client is consuming them. The socket need not send all of the bytes at once; it will eventually send them and they will be read in order at the other end. Messages are not guaranteed to be kept whole. You encounter a problem when you can read the `bufferlen` field but the whole corresponding message has not arrived yet.

Your client needs to continue reading from the socket until `bufferlen` bytes have been read.

Also be aware that the act of reading the `bufferlen` field may also need to be completed with multiple reads.